# Сортировка и RAND() в MYSQL

Tags: sql, сортировка, случайные-числа

`ORDER BY`tprice`DESC` и нужно добавить ещё `RAND()`. Как вернее это сделать?

```
ORDER BY `tprice` DESC RAND()
```

Что-то типа такого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть сортировка по tprice, то что вы, интересно, хотите получить?
Уж что-то одно - или по цене, или случайным образом. 
А если вы хотите сортировать случайным образом в группе одинаковых цен, тогда так:

```
ORDER BY tprice desc, rand()
```

Comment: @msi, я хочу перемешать просто эту сортировку по tprice.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Так?

Comment: @msi, ага. А ещё добавьте пожалуйста и `top` DESC

Comment: > А ещё добавьте пожалуйста и top DESC

А мне-то зачем. :-)

Comment: @msi, ну вы поняли же, что для меня :3 просто я не знаю как...

Comment: > просто я не знаю как...

Так же - через запятую.

Comment: Будьте готовы, что на больших таблицах - rand() - дырка по быстродействию, так как это не идексируемая сортировка, и я боюсь, что даже в режиме вторичной, оно все равно будет генерить мусор для каждой записи.

Comment: > Будьте готовы, что на больших таблицах - rand() - дырка по быстродействию

А к кому вы обращаетесь? :-)